# Override interface method PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, interface

I have the following code

```
class Model_MyAbstractClass {
}

class Model_MyClass extends Model_MyAbstractClass {

}
interface doStuff {

    function update(Model_MyAbstractClass $model);

}
class Mapper_MyClass implements doStuff{
     function update(Model_MyClass $model){
      }
}
```

So why doesn't this work in PHP? Model_MyClass is still a Model_MyAbstractClass.
I have 5 classes (maybe I'll have more) with similar methods. The whole difference is that each mapper has some model, all of them extend Model_MyAbstractClass.
If indeed there is no way of doing this, the only solutions left are: make an interface for each of them, with the only differences being the params (not DRY at all).
Check in each of the functions if the Model_MyAbstractClass is instance of Model_MyClass needed and throw an error - which seems like a silly strategy since I should be requiring explicitly the needed type of parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, that this is not working.

Your interface let assume, that you can pass **any** `Model_MyAbstractClass` to this function:

```
function update(Model_MyAbstractClass $model);
```

Here, you expect **only** a `Model_MyClass`:

```
class Mapper_MyClass implements doStuff{
     function update(Model_MyClass $model){    
     }
}
```

Sure, `Model_MyClass` is an instance of `Model_MyAbstractClass`. But the interface would assume, that you also can pass the class `Model_SomeOtherClass` which is extended from `Model_MyAbstractClass`.

Summary: You should be able to handle **ANY** `Model_MyAbstractClass` **NOT ONLY** `Model_MyClass`

---

What you possible Need:

```
class Mapper_MyClass implements doStuff
{
    function update(Model_MyAbstractClass $model)
    {
        //Do stuff on Model_MyAbstractClass

        //...

        if ($model instanceof Model_MyClass) {
            //Do additional stuff on Model_MyClass

            //...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Maybe you running into the same problem like me, which can be easily solved via `C#` and `Java`. For me it was, i wanted a `Generic` Base Class. So something like this:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
    function update(T $model)
}

class Bar extends Foo<Model_MyClass> {
}
```

This is current not possible with plain PHP, but [Facebook's Hack made it possible](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.generics.php). Problem is, this was no option for me, but maybe for you. I have done it with the way of using the `instanceof` as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to PHP, but is more of a misunderstanding how interfaces work in OOP concept.

From your code, interface `doStuff` has a method which takes `Model_MyAbstractClass` as its parameter, means the parameter instance will always be displayed as `Model_MyAbstractClass` and not anything else, doesn't matter if the given instance is instance of `Model_MyAbstractClass`, like in your example.

In an OOP language, such as Java, you will receive an error like this:

```
The method update(Model_MyAbstractClass) of type Mapper_MyClass must override or implement a supertype method
```

However, in PHP you can do `instanceof` checks, and in OOP languages you can `cast` to `Model_MyClass`